# Combine Close Votes review queue with flags to close

Tags: discussion, review, vote-to-close, flags

The Close Votes review queue and list of flags to close seem like they could be close enough in purpose to combine.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're already pretty much combined. When a user flags a question with a canned vote-to-close reason, the question will automatically appear in the Close Votes review queue.

As far as I'm aware, it still only takes one user to vote to close (act) on the flag in order for it to automatically get dismissed as helpful. I've voiced that it should dismiss as helpful when it actually gets closed and dismiss as declined if left open, but I was told that the interaction between the queues and flags is currently being revamped anyways.